# Use WITH clause inside a stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, common-table-expression

I want to use the `WITH` clause to fill a table inside a stored procedure. I was reading that said clause keeps the data in memory while the session is alive.

There is a table that has an information that I need to update that is called sprlink, but that table it has millions of records. Currently I have the update as follows but it is very slow:

```
open act_rpt_list_cdo;
loop
  fetch act_rpt_list_cdo bulk collect into v_act_rpt_list_cdo limit 100;
  for i in 1 .. v_act_rpt_list_cdo.count loop
    update RPT_LIST_CDO set name_cdo=(select trim(sln.linkvalue) from sprlink sln where sln.objectid=v_act_rpt_list_cdo(i).id  and SLN.LINKID = 164 and logidto=0),
                            date_cdo=(select trim(sln.linkvalue) from sprlink sln where sln.objectid=v_act_rpt_list_cdo(i).id  and SLN.LINKID = 165 and logidto=0),
                            cod_cdo=(select trim(sln.linkvalue) from sprlink sln where sln.objectid=v_act_rpt_list_cdo(i).id  and SLN.LINKID = 166 and logidto=0),
                            log_cdo=(select trim(sln.linkvalue) from sprlink sln where sln.objectid=v_act_rpt_list_cdo(i).id  and SLN.LINKID = 167 and logidto=0),
                            data_cdo=(select trim(sln.linkvalue) from sprlink sln where sln.objectid=v_act_rpt_list_cdo(i).id  and SLN.LINKID = 168 and logidto=0)

    where rowid=v_act_rpt_list_cdo(i).ri;
  end loop;
  exit when act_rpt_list_cdo%notfound;
end loop;
close act_rpt_list_cdo
```

I wanted to use the clause in this context limiting the records but I have no idea how to use it within a procedure:

```
WITH tt_sprlink AS (select sln.objectid as objectid , sln.linkid as linkid, trim(sln.linkvalue) linkvalue
   from sprlinks sln join RPT_LIST_CDO rpt on (sln.objectid=rpt.id and sln.logidto=0)
  where sln.linkid in (164,165,166,167,168))
select *
from tt_sprlink
```

To be able to do something in the following way since the tt_srplink would only have the necessary records for my update.

```
act_rpt_list_cdo
loop
  fetch act_rpt_list_cdo bulk collect into v_act_rpt_list_cdo limit 100;
  for i in 1 .. v_act_rpt_list_cdo.count loop
    update RPT_LIST_CDO set name_cdo=(select trim(sln.linkvalue) from tt_sprlink sln where sln.objectid=v_act_rpt_list_cdo(i).id  and SLN.LINKID = 164),
                            date_cdo=(select trim(sln.linkvalue) from tt_sprlink sln where sln.objectid=v_act_rpt_list_cdo(i).id  and SLN.LINKID = 165),
                            cod_cdo=(select trim(sln.linkvalue) from tt_sprlink sln where sln.objectid=v_act_rpt_list_cdo(i).id  and SLN.LINKID = 166),
                            log_cdo=(select trim(sln.linkvalue) from tt_sprlink sln where sln.objectid=v_act_rpt_list_cdo(i).id  and SLN.LINKID = 167),
                            data_cdo=(select trim(sln.linkvalue) from tt_sprlink sln where sln.objectid=v_act_rpt_list_cdo(i).id  and SLN.LINKID = 168)

    where rowid=v_act_rpt_list_cdo(i).ri;
  end loop;
  exit when act_rpt_list_cdo%notfound;
end loop;
close act_rpt_list_cdo
```

Any suggestion or idea please?

Comment: Did you consider MERGE statement or BULK UPDATE ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all: the statement that the `WITH` clauses "keeps the data in memory while the session is alive" is ***false***.  A `WITH cursor_var AS (SELECT ...) LOOP` construct is just a cursor loop -- the same as the `OPEN..FETCH..CLOSE` loop that you've got.  That said: there is a lot to like about `WITH` cursor loops, but magical data caching isn't one of them.

Second of all: unless you've omitted something, there seems to be no need for PL/SQL in this case.  Row-by-row cursor processing, as you have, will be much slower than a single SQL statement.  (Your case is even worse because you are doing 5 scalar subqueries for every update as well).

Here is how you might accomplish your goal using a single `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE rpt_list_cdo u
SET ( name_cdo, date_cdo, cod_cdo, log_cdo, data_cdo ) = 
(
SELECT MAX(DECODE(sln.linkid,164,trim(sln.linkvalue),null)) name_cdo,
       MAX(DECODE(sln.linkid,165,trim(sln.linkvalue),null)) date_cdo,
       MAX(DECODE(sln.linkid,166,trim(sln.linkvalue),null)) cod_cdo,
       MAX(DECODE(sln.linkid,167,trim(sln.linkvalue),null)) log_cdo,
       MAX(DECODE(sln.linkid,168,trim(sln.linkvalue),null)) data_cdo
FROM   sprlinks sln
WHERE  sln.objectid = u.id
AND    sln.linkid in (164,165,166,167,168))
WHERE 1=1
AND -- whatever other conditions you have in your act_rpt_list_cdo cursor
```

`MERGE` would also work, but I like `UPDATE` better in this case because it is easier to add whatever other conditions you have in your `act_rpt_list_cdo` cursor.

Comment: First time I see a way to evade those subqerys that take so long time to execution. One single query and it brings all the data I need and goes through the table only once. Thank you very much, how fast do you do now.

Comment: Just to add ... we *might* cache the contents of the WITH element, using something called 'cursor duration in-memory temporary tables' but its not something you have direct control over

Comment: @ConnorMcDonald I think the OP was asking about `WITH`-style cursor loops, not the `WITH` SQL clause.  Also, in no case would the data be cached "while the session is alive", as the OP's reading suggested.